# Большой вес файла после статической линковки Qt, как побороть?

Tags: c++, qt, кроссплатформенность, qml

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с задачей написать кроссплатформенную программу. Выбор сразу пал на Qt в связке с QML. На линуксе проблем с наличием самого Qt нет, но на Windows и OS X по умолчанию они не стоят, а заставлять пользователя устанавливать что-либо дополнительное выглядит странно. Поэтому решил использовать статическую линковку с Qt. На Windows размер библиотек получается а пределах 30-50 мб, а вот на OS X размер составляет 100-200 мб (при том, что сама среда разработки Qt весит на маке 10 гб). Для среднего приложения 200 мб библиотек это весьма странно. Вопрос: есть ли способ уменьшить размеры скомпилированного файла? Хотелось бы услышать советы от тех, кто постоянно пользуется Qt, как вы справляетесь с отсутствием самой Qt на многих системах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Молодой человек учите матчасть. Пусть статическая библиотека весит хоть гигабайт, из нее в конечный бинарь попадет только то что фактически используется.

Ну а вообще, по моим наблюдениям, размер конечного бинаря скомпилированного со статически собранной Qt примерно равен размеру такого же бинаря собранного с динамически собранной Qt плюс размер используемых дээлелек Qt. Хотя нередко это правило не выполняется. Вобщем нужно смотреть в каждом случае отдельно, если этот вопрос вас волнует.

Проблема отсутствия Qt на целевой системе решается установкой онной. Часто Qt упаковывают в инсталянт вместе со своим ПО и не парятся.

Comment: Общедоступный Qt имеет хитрые *.lib: код из них подгружает DLL в процессе работы, хоть все и статически собрано.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов да есть такое, но это немного на другую тему песня

Comment: IMHO тут как раз эта проблема: везде написано статика, а без DLL не работает.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ну вот прямо сейчас у меня работает прирожение собранное со статической Qt 5.5 которое не грузит никаких лишних DLL, при этом даже плагин JPEG не подргужается хотя использую каритнки в JPEG

Comment: А это вы Qt отдельно пересобирали или коммерческая версия какая?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Комъюнити сам пересобирал. Вообще не понятно как оно использует JPEG, потому как я ничего специально не линкую к приложению. Подгруженные DLL смотрю ProccesExplorer`ом. Набитые шишки напоминают, что часто геморой появляется там где происходит что-то непонятное...